# IAM Role via CloudFormation Error in Principle

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to create an IAM role via cloudformation for an existing IAM user as principle and an existing dynamodb table. I have verified through yamllint and yaml is well-formatted and yet cloudformation is complaining about malformatted file.

Following is my cloudformation template:

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
    Parameters:
      vTableName:
        Type: String
        Description: the tablename
        Default: arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:1234567:table/test-table
      vUserName:
        Type: String
        Description: New account username
        Default: mytestuser
    Resources:
      DynamoRoleForTest:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS:
                - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/${vUserName}'  
              Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole    
          Path: /
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: DynamoPolicy
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: 2012-10-17
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                  - Action:
                      - dynamodb:BatchGet*
                      - dynamodb:DescribeStream
                      - dynamodb:DescribeTable
                      - dynamodb:Get*
                      - dynamodb:Query
                      - dynamodb:Scan                                    
                    Resource: !Ref vTableName
```

and following is error I receive,when I try to create this template:

Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 237dd218-a2a2-4194-9063-104f8022cb80)

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not-needed `-` in your `Action`:

```
- Action:
```

Therefore, your template should be (removed `-`):

```
    AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
    Parameters:
      vTableName:
        Type: String
        Description: the tablename
        Default: arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:1234567:table/test-table
      vUserName:
        Type: String
        Description: New account username
        Default: mytestuser
    Resources:
      DynamoRoleForTest:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
        Properties:
          AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                AWS:
                - !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:user/${vUserName}'  
              Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole    
          Path: /
          Policies:
            - PolicyName: DynamoPolicy
              PolicyDocument:
                Version: 2012-10-17
                Statement:
                  - Effect: Allow
                    Action:
                      - dynamodb:BatchGet*
                      - dynamodb:DescribeStream
                      - dynamodb:DescribeTable
                      - dynamodb:Get*
                      - dynamodb:Query
                      - dynamodb:Scan                                    
                    Resource: !Ref vTableName
```

`Principle` is fine, assuming it exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes now it works. Is there any tool or linter which checks these syntax errors in cloudformation templates? Thanks

Comment: @FahdMirza No problem. There are some tools such as [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aws-scripting-guy.cform), but I haven't used it personally. Thus, don't if you it could detect the mistake.